# how to make iOS7 App for publish passbook, use ibeacon ( like MLB )

Tags: bluetooth, gps, ios7, passbook, ibeacon

I would like to make iOS7 Application like MLB

I was reading Article is http://www.engadget.com/2013/09/27/mlb-to-use-ios-7s-ibeacon/

this article said to  :

1. MLB application installed ,
2. Beacon(Bluetooth LE device) sendging Proximity UUID for MLB application,
3. MLB application make Passbook ticket or update ticket (and Lock screen update passbook)

This feature, Can only have one special applications for Apple authentication?

some articles said to :

**Location based marketing and Passbook tickets
This particular application makes iBeacons an extension of the geofencing Apple enabled in last year’s Passbook, which lets an installed pass, ticket or loyalty card popup on the lock screen when you cross the geofence threshold of a defined GPS location. Using BLE, a merchant or other provider can define more targeted “micro-locations” to trigger an alert, in some cases requiring that you be in the presence of an iBeacon in order to validate a Passbook entry .**

i don't understand 'particular application'...

iOS7 application can make publish passbook use iBeacon without user event?

(i don't know well english ;; sorry;;)

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please ask what specific things you need help with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluetooth Beacons support is a new addition to iOS 7.

Rather than using GPS, it works by determining the phone's location relevant to a Bluetooth beacon. These beacons constantly broadcast a UUID that identifies them. Beacons offer more accuracy indoors as GPS doesn't work that well in covered spaces.

The standard CoreLocation framework defines a new class called CLBeaconRegion:

> A CLBeaconRegion object defines a type of region that is based on the device’s proximity to a Bluetooth beacon, as opposed to a geographic location. A beacon region looks for devices whose identifying information matches the information you provide. When that device comes in range, the region triggers the delivery of an appropriate notification.

An apps can request to be informed when they are near these beacons. This is how the MLB app works. It is programmed to recognize these beacons and to provide the user with offers and information based on location.

In addition to support within apps, Passkit also provides the support these beacons. It works in roughly the same way. The pkpass file contains a list of UUIDs that identify various beacons and when the phone is near a beacon, the pass is shown on the lock screen.

You can read more about Passkit's support by looking at the package format guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/LowerLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH3-SW4

Hopefully that answers your question.